# Setting a string to a list value in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a list in TCL:

{word0} {word1} {word2} {word3}

I need to set a new string to one of the values in the list. What would the syntax be for that?

```
set test {$my_list 0}
set test [$my_list 0]
```

Neither work.

Sorry for the new question, but I'm not familiar with this syntax and not finding it in the docs.

Comment: What would you like as result? I'm not sure I understand your question otherwise.

Comment: The result should be word0. For $my_list 1 it would be word1 and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`lindex`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lindex.htm):

```
set my_list [list word0 word1 word2 word3]
set test [lindex $my_list 0]
puts $test
# => word0
```

In Tcl, the first element in a list has the index 0.

Comment: thanks, I'm used to lists being referenced by index implicitly.

Comment: @some1 The style you're talking about is more OO-like. Tcl's objects and classes tend to be heavier weight; they're not usually used for simple collection datatypes like lists or associative maps. (It would be possible to hack something in with `unknown`, but it would be a gross hack, slow and prone to not working as expected.)